# User command to reload file-local variables

Tags: buffers, file-local-variables

How can I easily reload file-local variables, after I have changes their values in the file buffer?

I know a work around

> Save and close the file and re-open.

But this is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: M-:  (hack-local-variables)

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled myself over a way to do this when looking at the Elisp code in `files.el`:

```
M-x normal-mode
```

This command re-applies the local file variable list by calling the function `hack-local-variables`. However `normal-mode` does a lot of other stuff too, so this is not *just* re-reading the local variables...

Comment: This is what the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) suggests: " Use the command ‘M-x normal-mode’ to reset the local variables and
major mode of a buffer according to the file name and contents,
including the local variables list if any"

Answer (score 2):

I use quite often `hack-local-variables` to set the file local variables without side-effect (such as re-loading the major mode). [giglair](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14046/gigiair) already suggested that in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51212/user-command-to-reload-file-local-variables#comment78940_51212).

**Warning:** It does not reset local variables. That means if you remove a variable from the list of local variables this variable is still bound (and set to the old value) after running `hack-local-variables`. I think that could be the reason why it is just a function and not an interactive command.

You can easily turn `hack-local-variables` into an interactive command with the following advice:

```el
(defun hack-local-variables-make-interactive (&rest _args)
  "Just add the `interactive'-specification to `hack-local-variables'."
  (interactive))

(advice-add 'hack-local-variables :before #'hack-local-variables-make-interactive)
```

I most often need `hack-local-variables` in Orgmode files. Therefore I wrote a context-aware binding for <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. It runs `hack-local-variables` when it is in a Local Variables section of an Orgmode document.

```el
(require 'subr-x)
(require 'org)

(defun org+-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-local-variables (&optional noerror)
  "Run `hack-local-variable' when we are in the \"Local Variables\" section.
If the Local Variables section is not found and NOERROR is nil or omitted
this function signals a user error."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (when-let ((heading (condition-case nil
                (save-excursion
                  (org-back-to-heading t)
                  (when (looking-at "\\*[[:space:]]")
                (cons (point)
                      (org-get-tags))))
              (error nil)))
           (heading-pos (car heading))
           (heading-tags (cdr heading))
           (re "^[[:space:]]*\\(#+\\)?[[:space:]]*\\(local[[:space:]]+\\(variables\\)\\|\\(end\\)\\):[[:space:]]*$")
           (local-variables-start
        (progn
          (save-excursion (re-search-backward re heading-pos t))
          (match-string 3)))
           (in-comment (match-string 1))
           (local-variables-end
        (progn
          (re-search-forward (format "%s\\|^\\*+[[:space:]]" re) nil t)
          (match-string 4))))
      (if (and local-variables-start local-variables-end
           (or in-comment
           (member "noexport" heading-tags)))
      (progn
        (hack-local-variables)
        (message "Hacked local variables")
        t)
    (user-error "Local Variables not found")
    ))))

(add-to-list 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook #'org+-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-local-variables)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just use `find-alternate-file` which is bound to `C-x C-v` by default. `C-x C-v Ret` is lightning fast for me. `revert-buffer` will also work, but `M-x revert-buffer Ret` is more typing.

Both of these options will reset local variables. For instance, if you have `indent-tabs-mode: nil` in your local variable list and you remove it outright, save, `find-alternate-file` or `revert-buffer` your buffer, `indent-tabs-mode` will now be set to `t` (assuming you haven't changed its default elsewhere of course.) Note: I only confirmed this with file-local variables, and not directory-local variables.

@drew brings up a good point. If you're not careful, or use these functions non-interactively you can overwrite unsaved changes in your buffer. Also, if you have unsaved changes, using these functions can break your flow. `find-alternate-file` will ask to save your buffer, and `revert-buffer` will ask to overwrite your unsaved changes. As you develop muscle memory and good editing habit, you'll find it gets in your way less and less.

Comment: That's generally what I do too (I have `<f5>` bound to reverting without confirmation). But of course reverting can lose other changes too, so you might want to save the buffer or some other things before doing it.